# How to make some programs closed by only Administrator in AD GPO

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

In domain computers, some programs are working, and users can close that application (or kills with taskkill), is there any possibility to ask admin creditentials when they try to close that application ?

Answer (score 1):

No. Simple like that. A program started by a user runs under user credentials and blocking closing it is going to cause a nightmare of problems in case of one of many malfunctions - among other things people could not install patches or reboot computers out of principle.

So no, and in 30 years I never heard that as requirement.

Comment: Actually the program is working as an agent program and it is started by administrator.

Comment: Ah, no? Then it should be a windows service and the user is not an admin? not my job to provide proper explanation on the question, please go back and think before formulating it.